# How to not escape pipe redirection symbols in Cygwin

Tags: bash, cmd, cygwin, quoting

I’ve got build scripts working perfectly for Linux bash. Currently I’d like to adapt build for Cygwin, to make it cross-platform. The problem is the build script uses pipe redirection like `|` and `>`, which need to be escaped with `^` when using with Cygwin’s ‘bash -c’.

I’m wondering is there any solution to not escape every pipe redirection symbol for Cygwin, maybe bash command line option or env var.

The example:

`ls -l | tee 1.log`, working perfectly in Linux, needs to be escaped in the following way to be used with Cygwin’s `bash -c`:

`ls -l ^| tee 1.log`

Comment: Sounds like you start `bash -c` from inside windows `cmd`, hence the (horrible) quoting rules of cmd / Windows' CreateProcess apply, therefore I tagged the question as `cmd`.

Comment: This is certainly not the case. In contrary, `ls -l ^| tee 1.log` would produce an error message, unliss you do have a directory named `^`. I doubt that you are using bash. Do a `echo $BASH_VERSION` and let us know what you see. In particular, post the **exact** steps we have to do to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume `bash -c "ls -l | tee 1.log"` should do the trick for symbols like `|` and `>`. But if you want to use `"` inside the bash command, you *might* run into problems again (depends on the actual use of quotes, and how Cycgwin implemented/[compiled](https://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINARGV) bash).

In general, it would be safer to either run bash interactively and input the command there; or (if not possible) use a script file instead, e.g. `bash script.sh`.

Comment: It's a pity that there is no magic command line option to fix this.

Comment: The quoting chaos on Windows is baked into the design of the OS, so I understand that it is probably impossible to fix without breaking changes. Some software has its own brutal workarounds. E.g. [`powershell -EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-encodedcommand-base64encodedcommand). But it doesn't seem like cygwin bash offers such workarounds.